# Why isn't my data class member directly available?

Tags: javascript, class, object, scope, member

I've been using jQuery for a couple of years now with very limited understanding of vanilla javascript.  Scope, the object model, and many of the design patterns that I see used in javascript baffle me.  I'm trying to implement a class that will eventually be used in a scheduling plugin that I need to write and I'm having a hard time understanding why data stored in one of my class members doesn't seem to be available.  I'm not sure if the issue is with scope or some other behavior that I don't understand.

I have the following code with 2 questions in the comments at the appropriate places.  The first question is whether or not my scope workaround in my getJSON call is the correct way of handling the scope issue inside getJSON.  My second question is why I can't directly access schedule.data.

```
function Schedule() {
    this.year = null;
    this.month = null;
    this.day = null;

    this.start_datetime = null;
    this.start_timestamp = null;
    this.end_datetime = null;
    this.end_timestamp = null;

    this.data = [];

    return this;
}

Schedule.prototype.init = function() {
    var url = '/tripsys/new_admin/employee_schedule/get_employee_schedule_data/' + this.start_timestamp + '/' + this.end_timestamp;
    var self = this; // 1. trying to work around scope issues.  Is this the correct way to handle the scope problems here?
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        self.data = data;
    }); 
}

var schedule = new Schedule();

$(document).ready(function() {
    schedule.year = $('#year').text();
    schedule.month = $('#month').text();
    schedule.day = $('#day').text();
    schedule.start_datetime = new Date(schedule.year, schedule.month - 1, schedule.day);
    schedule.start_timestamp = Math.round(schedule.start_datetime.getTime() / 1000);
    schedule.end_datetime = new Date(schedule.year, schedule.month - 1, schedule.day, 23, 59, 59);
    schedule.end_timestamp = Math.round(schedule.end_datetime.getTime() / 1000);

    schedule.init();
    console.log(schedule); // if I log the whole schedule object the data that I expect to be in the "data" member is there
    console.log(schedule.data); // 2. why is the data that I expect to be in the "data" member not there when I access schedule.data directly?
});
```

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: On a side note, you really should understand the language you are working with, especially after using it for 2 years.  I would suggest reading up a bit on the subject.

Comment: I agree.  In the past I've done more backend work and never needed to do anything more with javascript than some simple dom manipulation which jQuery abstracts away really nicely.  It's time to start getting a better understanding of javascript.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense.  I'm just now teaching myself web programming now, which of course involves learning js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well point number one is correct in that you need to save the `this` reference while you still can because when the inner function is called by jQuery, `this` inside the function will refer to the ajax object.

In the second comment you are logging `schedule.data` before the ajax request has completed. You can see `schedule.data` when you log `schedule` because when you log an object in google chrome, the object properties are retrieved after you manually "expand" the object in chrome console. When you manually "expand" it, at that time the request has already completed.

You can reproduce it like this:

```
var a = {};
console.log(a); //do not "expand" the object properties yet
console.log(a.property); //undefined
a.property = "value";
//"expand" the already logged object and it will have "value"
```

Comment: Yep, I am using chrome and I see what you mean with your example of "opening" a object in the console.  Perfect explanation!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because in this line `schedule.init();`, it makes an ajax call which has not completed yet when you then do `console.log(schedule.data);`.  Ajax calls are asynchronous.  Calling them only starts the networking operation and then they return immediately.  They are not completed until the success handler function has been called (and that's when `self.data` is assigned).

So, if you want to look at the data for the schedule object that was obtained in the `.init()` function, you have to wait until that ajax call has completed or do something with the data in the completion function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, that will work, although it isn't a scope issue as much as it uses variable scope to get around a *context* issue.
2. To access `schedule.data`, you need to wait until the data has arrived. In other words, place the `console.log` code in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the ajax call has not returned before you log the object.  If you want to make the ajax call synchronous and the `init` function gets a result before you log, use the `async` param on an ajax jQuery call:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: url,  
    dataType: 'json',  
    async: false,  
    success: function(data){  
      self.data = data;
      console.log(data);
    }  
});
```

Comment: synchronous asynchronous javascript and xml

Comment: Note: Making ajax calls synchronous will lock up the browser for the duration of the networking operation.  This is generally not the best way to code a web app.